# Oracle 10g SQL plus username, password + Host string unkown

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have just installed Oracle 10g database and also oracle developer suit, which is installed as DevSuiteHome1 in my computer. I could not use SQL plus because I dont know the exact username, password and host string to connect. During installation I did not ask to enter any username & password. Then what would be the username,password + host string? Help me out of this. 
[image]

Comment: Did you actually create a database during the installation? If you did, it did ask you for the name & for some passwords.

Comment: no.
just install oracle 10g xe. just asked for password and i give admin for that.
after this i install oracle developer but again nothing asked ..

Comment: Why did you install a totally outdated Oracle version in 2014? And why are you using an even more outdated client tool (iSQL*Plus) which isn't even supported any more. The Oracle installer will have created several accounts: `SYSTEM`, `SYS` and most probably `HR` and `SCOTT` as well. Try `system/manager` or `scott/tiger` to logon. I have never used `iSQL*Plus` so I am not sure what the host string is supposed to be but try `localhost` or simply `XE` there

Comment: @a_horse, that's not iSQL*Plus, that's the windows version of SQL*Plus (sqlplusw.exe, IIRC)

Comment: I think @a_horse is correct, however, that the values needed will be `system`, `manager` and `XE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Retrieve detail of database service name/host string:

1. Open cmd.
2. Issue command `lsnrctl status`.
3. Usually, only one database service name will be listed. good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can connect many user:-
 scott which password is tiger
hr which password is hr

you can connect also sys user. 
For connect sys user, only write in user name:- / as sysdba